# Can a Github issue tracker be exported or migrated to another tracking system

Tags: json, github, migration, export, issue-tracking

I am thinking about using the github issue tracker as an experiment, but leaving open the option to migrate to a more powerful issue tracker if our developer community finds the github tracker lacking. However, I can't find any information about such migration except [this blog post](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/Github-To-Jira-Bug-Migration-Script)
and [this github article](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository)
which tells me how to export, but not how to get the resulting JSON into another issue tracker.

Is there specific information available on how to
 accomplish this?

Comment: Your question is quite vague... do you have run into any problem on which you want help?

Answer (score 0):

Specific import information will be specific to the tracking system you are importing into.

In general however like the JIRA example you linked to, you will probably need to switch the Github provided JSON to a CSV or XML file. Some of the keys may also need to be renamed. All of this should be manageable by writing or finding a short script for the task.